# Rename the graph in cosmos db graph api?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Is there a way to rename the graph in cosmos DB graph API?

I did not find any direct option to rename the graph, the options available are create graph and delete database.

Comment: you want to rename the collection?

Comment: It's not possible to rename resources in Cosmos DB. You will need to create a new graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is **no method to rename a graph in CosmosDB**. You can update/rename vertex or property.

You can share this idea and feedback to Azure [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/feedback/).